# Swift reloadData on collectionView from outside of controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller with a collectionView that pulls item data from an API.
The data is stored in a struct->static variable. I need to access this data from multiple areas in the app.

How can I reload the tableView data when the API data comes in?

Controller

```
class CollectionsViewController: UIViewController {

}


extension CollectionsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Brand.products.count
    }
}
```

API data

```
struct Brand{
    static var products:[Product] = []

    static func fetchProducts(){


        let url = URL(string: "www.someAPIexample.com")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            do{
               // update data (cut this part for readability)
               self.products = data
               // reload the controller.collectionView that uses this
               (how do I get this controller from here).collectionView.reloadData()

            }catch{
                print(error)
            }


        }).resume()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to add a completion handler

```
static func fetchProducts(completion: () -> Void) {

    ...


    self.products = data
    completion()

    ...    
}
```

And call it

```
Brand.fetchProducts() {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
   }
}
```